# Converting iPhone App to iPad - Want to keep sandbox Data & CoreData storage

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, sandbox

I have an iPhone Application that I would like to port to the iPad.  Many user already have the iPhone App installed on their iPad.

I would like to push out a Universal App, though I'm not sure if the Sandbox data will still be there on the iPad once the iPhone app is upgraded to the new universal app.

Will I have all of my CoreData stuff there?

Thanks,
   Scott<-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Apps’ user defaults, documents, etc. are preserved between updates. The only case in which this wouldn’t work would be if you released a separate app with a separate bundle identifier, but since you’re just turning into a Universal build that shouldn’t be an issue.